# where can I buy this door strike plate (Germany or online)?

Tags: door-frame, product-recommendation

In an apartment in Germany, I want to replace several gold-coloured strike plates with silver/steel-coloured ones. (Currently five are gold, two are silver and all door handles are silver.) The problem is that I am unable to find this part for sale anywhere and I have spent a long time searching!

The features of this particular strike plate are:

- "corner" strike plate
- 200mm long, 22mm wide and 7-8mm deep, metal ~2mm thick
- there is no left or right variant as it is symmetrical
- rounded ends on both sides of the "corner" at both ends
- off-centre countersunk screw holes
- slight bulge in the middle of the slots for latch and lock bolt (though I am not sure this is important)

Here's a photo:

[image]

There is no text on either side.

I have searched the likes of Hagebaumarkt, Obi, Hornbach, Amazon.de/com/co.uk and googled but all plates lack either the right length, the right depth or the rounded ends and I am beginning to wonder if this size is not longer a standard (or perhaps it never was).

There are plates available without the rounded corners and, in theory, I could extend the recess in the doorframe in order to accomodate non-rounded corners, but I think my carpentry skills are not up time this an I would damage the veneer, and so I would really prefer not to go this way.

If anybody has ideas regarding where I could obtain this part then it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked the apartment landlord/management where they got them?  They usually keep records of that type somewhere.  For making square ones fit, usually only need a pencil, wood chisel and a hammer to square the opening.

Comment: Of course a hacksaw and a file would round off the corners if you don’t want to square the corners.

Comment: Look for markings on the back of this piece or on the other parts of the lock set.  Take it all apart if necessary to look.  Take the piece  to a good locksmith shop (not a big hardware store) in your town or region (not anywhere else, not online) and talk to the owner (not the teenage assistant).  Ask the landlord.   If you live in a large building (hundreds or thousands of doors)  these may have been custom made.

Comment: The bulge is interesting.  I bet the person who designed it would say it's important. :)

Comment: The question got closed, but I'd like to thank the people who suggested things! I'll contact the housing management company, otherwise I'll try hacksaw and file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you shop for the part you need (shopping questions are off-topic here) but I would suggest that you explore the option of nickel plating your plates. If they are currently brass or brass plated, the plates can be nickel plated easily. Amazon and other retailers have home nickel plating kits. If the plate is covered with lacquer, the lacquer must be removed first.

If you need advice on removing lacquer from brass, and you can't find the method online, you can post a question here and someone is sure to help you.

Comment: There are also metal refinishing businesses if you want a professional job or don't want to do it yourself. They can change the finish from, say, brass, to satin nickel, or any other desired color/look. This can be expensive, though. Viel Glück!